# F# type inferrence issue with linq and possibly entity framework

Tags: f#, type-inference

Just trying to do something simple like this:

```
context.Users.Any(fun currentUser -> currentUser.UserName = userName)
```

Where Context is just an entity framework context.  Now when I hover over "currentUser" it knows that it is a User type.  However I get the:

> Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to
>   this program point. A type annotation may be needed prior to this
>   program point to constrain the type of the object. This may allow the
>   lookup to be resolved.

Now I realize that I can do this:

```
context.Users.Any(fun (currentUser:User) -> currentUser.UserName = userName)
```

But that seems really silly since c# can easily infer type with:

```
context.Users.Any(currentUser => currentUser.UserName = userName)
```

Full method is this:

```
let FindAndRemoveUser(userName:String, context:StoryBoardContext) =
  if context.Users.Any(fun currentUser-> currentUser.UserName = userName) then
    let foundUser = context.Users.Where(fun innerUser -> innerUser.UserName = userName).First()
    context.Users.DeleteObject(foundUser)
    context.SaveAll() |> ignore
```

Am I wrong for thinking that F# should handle type inference as well or better than C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that your approach has a more fundamental issue than just the problem you described. When you use `Where` or `Any` with a lambda expression in C#, the C# compiler turns the lambda into an expression tree `Expression<Func<_, _>>` and so LINQ to Entities can translate the code to an SQL query.

However, when you use F# lambda function as an argument, it will be compiled as a function (or a delegate of type `Func<_, _>`). This means that your code will call in-memory version of the processing function and you'll do all processing in memory instead of doing it on the database server!

To write a query in F# 2.0, you need to wrap all code inside a quotation and run it using `query` function from [F# PowerPack](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/) (F# 3.0 is going to make this a lot nicer, but that's unfortunately just a beta). You probably need something like this:

```
if query <@ context.Users |> Seq.exists (fun currentUser -> 
              currentUser.UserName = userName) @> then
     let foundUser = 
       query <@ context.Users 
                |> Seq.filter (fun usr -> usr.UserName = userName) 
                |> Seq.head @>
     context.Users.DeleteObject(foundUser)  
     context.SaveAll() |> ignore
```

(Aside, I'm not sure if you need to check whether a user exists upfront - you can just find all users using just `filter` and then delete the first one if the returned sequence contains something)

Comment: Nice... really glad I asked this question.  I've been wanting a reason to look into the power pack, now it seems unquestionable.

Comment: @Programmin : Only until F# 3.0 (hopefully). :-]

Answer (score 2):

I suppose `context.Users` is a `seq<User>`, so you can use high-order functions on `Seq` module. In contrast with Linq, you will benefit from type inference in F# sequences:

```
let FindAndRemoveUser(userName:String, context:StoryBoardContext) =
  if context.Users |> Seq.exists (fun currentUser -> currentUser.UserName = userName) then
    let foundUser = context.Users |> Seq.filter (fun innerUser -> innerUser.UserName = userName) |> Seq.head
    context.Users.DeleteObject(foundUser)
    context.SaveAll() |> ignore
```

There is an interesting thread regarding type inference in Linq and F# sequences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698133/f-method-chaining-vs-pipe-operator).

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a IQueryable, not an IEnumerable, so this won't work... I think you should use PowerPack's quotation-to-LINQ-expression translator: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2009/10/23/a-quick-refresh-on-query-support-in-the-f-power-pack.aspx