# Static function in fsharp on usual classes

Tags: f#, extension-methods, static-methods

I constantly call static methods calling the static class, and this seems unnatural to me:

```
let l = Seq.length myseq
```

It would be more natural to me to use

```
let l =  myseq.length
```

you can imagine it is the same for many base class

Is there a way to have all those methods available automatically as instance method, without writing extension methods for each of them ?

Comment: I can see what you mean but I think some of that is the conditioning of the OO mindset that many of us are in.  We're used to thinking of methods on objects as opposed to thinking of functions taking arguments.

Comment: You may find [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7698133/162396) helpful.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci I totally agree, this is plain dumb OO style, and might hurt functionnal betterment. but for simple properties like this, I feel it is better. not to mention Intellisense which I think is a strong feature. Since there is a one to one relation ship, it is not without sense to use the form that yields the lowest amount of verbosity. but I completely agree with your statement.

Comment: I am just a taliban  when it comes to code verbosity

Comment: @nicolas If you're a taliban with regards to code verbosity, welcome to functional programming--you'll be right at home here. :-)  Seriously though, I can see what you're getting at but as I say it's more of a question of thinking in terms of functions taking arguments as opposed to members of classes.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci yes, I really appreciate cutting code and with long expression, FP works really well. just crafted a Seq.groupByThenBy function and even in this imple case, its pretty clear FP is the way to go

Comment: Hehe, I've been thinking about going in the opposite direction: creating first-class functions from instance methods. Once you grok the power of function composition, you'll see that OO is generally *more* verbose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, there is no way to treat values from modules as if they are instance members.  However, in the case of the `Seq` module, you can find extension member analogs of many of the `Seq` functions in the `System.Linq` namespace, so you can do:

```
open System.Linq

let arr = [| 1 .. 10 |]
let ct = arr.Count()
let arr2 = arr.Select(fun i -> i + 1)
// etc.
```

Comment: Very nice. did not know about the Linq trick. I might publish some other extensions methods through github for the like minded peeps. thank you.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning the downside to doing this.

Comment: As a habitual coding style, it requires excessive type annotations and is non-idiomatic compared to functions.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way to have all those methods available automatically as instance method, without writing extension methods for each of them ?

No. And even if you did, you'd lose the benefits of type inference in F#.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the pipe operator?

```
let l = myseq |> Seq.length
```

Edit: 
Or

```
let l = myseq.Count()
```

Edit 2:

As kvb pointed out Count() requires System.Linq

Comment: it is even more verbose... although I agree it fits better within the 'functional' paradigm in that it composes

Comment: I am a newbie in F#, but while playing around in Linqpad I noticed that a sequence (in F#) implements a enumerator. So I tried myseq.Count() and it seems to work!

Answer (score 0):

Is it the fact that you don't have Intellisense helping you to see what action is available that bothers you?

Like Umair wrote above, the pipelining style is in a certain way the closest way you're looking for. But indeed, you have to know the right module in which the functions are defined.

Comment: of course intellisense is Good, but low redundancy is waht bugs me most. fsharp already knows I am dealing with a seq. Beside code reduction, i feel it goes more with the flow. the object oriented flow though. I guess i'll use pipeline style as a best approximation.