# Functions vs methods

Tags: f#

I'm very new to F#. One of the first things I noticed was that collection operations are defined as functions rather than as methods.

As an experiment, I defined a couple of methods on `list`:

```
type List<'a> with
    member this.map f = List.map f this
    member this.filter f = List.filter f this
```

Then, given these helpers:

```
let square x = x * x

let isEven n = n % 2 = 0
```

here's an example of using the methods:

```
[1 .. 10].filter(isEven).map(square)
```

And here's the traditional way:

```
[1 .. 10] |> List.filter isEven |> List.map square
```

So concision clearly wasn't a reason to choose functions over methods. :-)

From a library design perspective, why were functions chosen over methods?

My guess is that it's because you can pass `List.filter` around, but can't really pass the `filter` method around unless it's "tied" to a list or wrapped in an anonymous function (i.e. `(fun (ls : 'a list) -> ls.filter)` effectively turns the `filter` method back into a function on `list`).

However, even with that reason, it seems the most common case of invoking an operation directly would give favor to methods since they are more concise. So I'm wondering if there's another reason.

Edit:

My second guess is function specialization. I.e. it's straightforward to specialize `List.filter` (e.g. `let evens List.filter isEven`). It seems more verbose to have to define an `evens` method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [f# Method Chaining vs |> Pipe Operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698133/f-method-chaining-vs-pipe-operator)

Comment: Please note that member names go in `CamelCasing`, not `camelCasing`.

Comment: @RamonSnir it's `PascalCasing` :)

Comment: @rarouš Pascal is for physicists, Caml is for programmers :P

Answer (score 6):

What functions have over methods is function specialization and the easy factoring it enables.

Here's the example expression involving functions:

```
let square x = x * x

let isEven n = n % 2 = 0

[1 .. 10] |> List.filter isEven |> List.map square
```

Let's factor out a function called `evens` for filtering evens:

```
let evens = List.filter isEven
```

And now let's factor out a function which squares a list of ints:

```
let squarify = List.map square
```

Our original expression is now:

```
[1 .. 10] |> evens |> squarify
```

Now let's go back to the original method based expression:

```
[1 .. 10].filter(isEven).map(square)
```

Factoring out a filter on evens isn't as trivial in this case.

Answer (score 4):

I think your guess is correct. Concision aside, being able to treat `List.filter` as a first class thing that may be passed around (your first guess) and partially applied (your second guess) is key. It's a verb- rather than noun-oriented way of looking at the world. I think [Steve Yegge said it best](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2006/03/execution-in-kingdom-of-nouns.html) :)